# C# Stop On Collision

Tags: c#, collision-detection, collision

So I have a game that I'm working on and its a simple platformer kind of like mario bros, I have a simple physics engine to move the player (Things like gravity e.t.c), But I have no idea how I would go about stopping an objects movement on collision, the best I've managed to do is to stop all movement if it collides with an object, but it is still left intersecting the object and can not move at all as the movement script is just turned off at that point.

Any help with the theory or snippets of code would be appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe you can try to set the velocity of said object to 0 on collision. I am not sure if that will help you in that scenario. Unsure what engine you use, but for unity: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-gameObject.html

Comment: Your best bet would be to use a pre-made 2d physics engine like [box2d](https://github.com/benukhanov/box2d-netstandard). Physics is really hard and the problem you have is super non-trivial unfortunatly.